# How can I pass object while navigating?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have main page on which I have collection view. I want to navigate to next page after I click submit button .I am able to navigate to the next page but I also want total list of items which I have in my collection how can I achieve that?

Comment: We can’t help you if you don’t post any code that shows what you’re doing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the detail of your code, but you can try to pass the total list of items as the parameter of the next page.(suppose it's name is `SecondPage`)

You can refer to the following code:

**MainPage.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    MyViewModel myViewModel;
    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

        myViewModel = new MyViewModel();    
        BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }

      private    void mCollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
        string previous = (e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyModel)?.Name;
        string current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyModel)?.Name;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here we can pass the data we need.
        var secondPage = new SecondPage(myViewModel.Data);

        await Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCollectionApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiCollectionApp"
             x:Name="myPage"
             >

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{ Binding Data}" x:Name="mCollectionView" 
                    SelectionChanged="mCollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout  Margin="3" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Car.Make}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />

                        <Button Text="delete"  Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                Command="{Binding  Path= BindingContext.RemoveEquipmentCommand,Source={Reference mCollectionView }}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  
                                 />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>


        <Button Text="submit" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="10"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public  ObservableCollection<MyModel> Data { get; set; }

        public ICommand RemoveEquipmentCommand => new Command<MyModel>(ReMoveItem);

        private void ReMoveItem(MyModel obj)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" the selected item's name  is:  " + obj.Name   );

            Data.Remove(obj);
        }

        public MyViewModel() {
            Data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

            Data.Add(new MyModel { Name ="model_1", Car= new Vehicle {Make="Make1" } });
            Data.Add(new MyModel { Name = "model_2", Car = new Vehicle { Make = "Make2" } });
            Data.Add(new MyModel { Name = "model_3", Car = new Vehicle { Make = "Make3" } });
            Data.Add(new MyModel { Name = "model_4", Car = new Vehicle { Make = "Make4" } });
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**SecondPage.cs**

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage 
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Items { get; set; }
    public SecondPage(ObservableCollection<MyModel> data )
      {     // we can get the passed data here
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Items = data;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jessie, but I want to pick some files using file picker and then want to populate that files in collection view. Once I click next then I want to navigate to the next page with all the files I have selected. I don't want to set data manually in view model

Comment: `but I want to pick some files using file picker and then want to populate that files in collection view.`   This is another problem. One problem, one thread. For the new problem, you can create a new problem. We are all willing to help you. :)

Comment: Hi @PreetiJadhav, could you please mark my reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)